# Multiple ViewHolder RecycleVIew List rearrange

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I tried to find the solution but I think nobody had such a problem.

So I have been using `ListView` in most of my projects and I feel it is more flexible in terms of not having to `Bind` with `ViewHolder` as you need to do in `RecyclerView`. But since I needed to make a horizontal `listview` I could easily do that with `LayoutManager` using `RecyclerView`. It works perfectly.

But now I am using multiple `ViewHolders` for `RecyclerView` because I need to display different views for different items of the `RecyclerView`. It again works perfectly using the code below.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Item> data;
    private Context context;

    // Item.Type is an enum, used to differentiate the view types.

    public MyAdapter(List<Item> list, Context context) {
        this.data = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(data.get(viewType).getType() == TYPEA) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.type_a, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolderA(itemView);
        }
        else {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.type_b, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolderB(itemView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if ( data.get(position).getType()== TYPEA ){
            ViewHolderA viewHolder = (ViewHolderA) holder;
            ...

        }
        else if (data.get(position).getType()== TYPEB){
            ViewHolderB viewHolder = ((ViewHolderB) holder);
            ...            
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {        
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {        
        return data.size();
    }

}
```

So the problem arises when I rearrange the list used to display the items. For instance, I start off with 1 item in the list of `TYPEB`, it is displayed correctly. But now I want to add new item in the list but at the start, so that `TYPEB` is pushed back. So i add a new item of `TYPEA` and the list looks like `[TYPEA,TYPEB]`. `ViewHolderA` is for `TYPEA` and similarly `ViewHolderB` for `TYPEB`

In this situation the line inside `onBindViewHolder`

```
ViewHolderA viewHolder = (ViewHolderA) holder;
```

Throws me an error saying that `ViewHolderB` can not be cast to `ViewHolderA`. That shows after rearranging the list, the adapter is calling `onBindViewHolder` with wrong `ViewHolder` instance against the `positon`. Any idea how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a unique id here, you don't have to return the position:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {        
    return data.get(position).getType()
}
```

And of course you have to use the viewType parameter as a type not as a position:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if(viewType == TYPEA) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.type_a, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderA(itemView);
    }
    else {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.type_b, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderB(itemView);
    }
}
```